# Limiting the number of updated/deleted rows in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

It is very easy to make mistakes when it comes to `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements in SQL Server Management Studio. You can easily delete way more than you want if you had a mistake in the `WHERE` condition or, even worse, delete the whole table if you mistakenly write an expression that evaluates to TRUE all the time.

Is there anyway to disallow queries that affects a large number of rows from within SQL Server Management Studio? I know there is a feature like that in MySQL Workbench, but I couldn't find any in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You can use SET ROWCOUNT to limit the updation of rows to number of count we want.

Comment: Why not just do a select count(*) from table where ... first?

Comment: @PareshJ: From [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx): "Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in a future release of SQL Server". Don't rely on this.

Comment: @StuartLC, well, it is not about writing the correct SQL statement, more than about making sure that no body else, specifically junior team members, can make big mistakes inadvertently.

Comment: Paresh J and Blam, same as above, I just want to make sure to put a security on the whole of SSDS to stop juniors from making mistakes.

Comment: A limit of X is not going to stop them from making mistakes.  And stop at X is not going to stop loss of data.  You need a test system and backups.

Answer (score 8):

No.

It is your responsibility to ensure that:

- Your data is properly backed up, so you can restore your data after making inadverdent changes.
- You are not writing a new query from scratch and executing it directly on a production database without testing it first.
- You execute your query in a transaction, and review the changes before committing the transaction.
- You know how to properly filter your query to avoid issuing a `DELETE`/`UPDATE` statement on your entire table. If in doubt, always issue a `SELECT *` or a `SELECT COUNT(*)`-statement first, to see which records will be affected.
- You don't rely on some silly feature in the front-end that might save you at times, but that will completely screw you over at other times.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good comments already said. Just one tiny addition: I have created a solution to prohibit occasional execution of DELETE or UPDATE without any WHERE condition at all. This is implemented as "Fatal actions guard" in my add-in named SSMSBoost.

Answer (score 1):

*(My comments were getting rather unwieldy)*

One simple option if you are uncertain is to `BEGIN TRAN`, do the update, and if the `rows affected` count is significantly different than expected, `ROLLBACK`, otherwise, do a few checks, e.g. `SELECTs` to ensure just the intended data was updated, and then `COMMIT`. The caveat here is that this will lock rows until you commit / rollback, and potentially require escalation to `TABLOCK` if a large number of rows are updated, so you will need to have the checking scripts planned in advance.

That said, in any half-serious system, no one, not even senior DBA's, should really be executing direct ad-hoc DML statements on a prod DB (and arguably the formal UAT DB too) - this is what tested applications are meant for (or tested, verified patch scripts executed only after change control processes are considered).

In less formal dev environments, does it really matter if things get broken? In fact, if you are an advocate of [Chaos Monkey](http://blog.codinghorror.com/working-with-the-chaos-monkey/), having juniors break your data might be a good thing in the long run - it will ensure that your process re scripting, migration, static data deployment, integrity checking are all in good order?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is **disable auto commit**. where you can **commit** your changes after review it. and commit it before ending the session.

for more details you can please follow the MSDN link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx

Comment: I disagree that this is a great feature. How should it know when to kick in? Whenever you affect 25% or 50% or 75% of the records in a table? What if you _intended_ to affect all the records? What if your table is very big and you only wanted to affect 1 record, but instead affected 5% which could still be millions of rows? Don't let the front-end do the thinking. The DBA should do the thinking.

Comment: I checked this option and I guess it creates another risk if the user forget to commit/rollback transaction.